# Forge 1.11 Texturing Problems

Tags: textures, minecraft, modeling, minecraft-forge

As forge standards have recently changed, it is hard to find applicable posts already on this site, so I have resorted to posting one myself. I am trying to add a texture/model to an item, but upon compiling, I see this:

[image]

I register the model using the following code, invoked through the client proxy in the init phase:

```java
Minecraft.getMinecraft().getRenderItem().getItemModelMesher().register(item, 0, new ModelResourceLocation(modid + ":" + item.getUnlocalizedName().substring(5), "inventory"));
```

"item" and "modid" are properly defined in the scope above.

Here is my standard item model which the item inherits from, located at src/main/resources/assets/ultramc/models/item:

```json
{
"thirdperson_righthand": {
"rotation": [ 0, 0, 0 ],
"translation": [ 0, 3, 1 ],
"scale": [ 0.55, 0.55, 0.55 ]
},
"firstperson_righthand": {
"rotation": [ 0, -90, 25 ],
"translation": [ 1.13, 3.2, 1.13],
"scale": [ 0.68, 0.68, 0.68 ]
}
}
```

... and the actual child model located at the same spot:

```json
{
"parent":"ultramc:item/basic_item",
"textures": {
    "layer0":"ultramc:items/iron_nugget"
}
}
```

The texture in question is a 16x16 png file located at src/main/resources/assets/ultramc/textures/items and is named iron_nugget.png.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, I followed the tutorial very closely. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Here is my source folder, because why not.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vSKj.png

Comment: You have curly quotes in your second JSON file; that _might_ cause this

Comment: Thanks, I fixed that, but that doesn't seem to be the problem.

Comment: Just curious, but could this be a problem with the standard model? The one i used does seem pretty dated -- it doesn't have a left-hand model. Perhaps that's the problem?

Comment: It might be.  I'm not too experienced with models, though; assuming that the second file is named something reasonable (`iron_nugget.json`, I think) everything should probably work.  I'm interested in figuring out what the issue is.

Comment: The moment when you finally solve your issue and realize that the iron nugget is already in 1.11.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out finally.

First of all, the "basic item" JSON was a bad idea. using `item/generated` is perfectly fine. Here is the code for those in the future that may need this:

```
{
    "parent": "item/generated",
    "textures": {
        "layer0": "modid:item_name"
    }
}
```

Also, one thing: textures should not be under `assets.modid.textures.items`, but instead simply under `assets.modid.textures` unless you want to update the "layer0" JSON to `modid:items/item_name`. Heck, you could have a whole organization system under your textures folder and it would work as long as you put it right in the model file.

One last word of advice: make sure the model file name is exactly the same as the unlocalized item name of your item, or it won't work. Oh yeah, the texture should always be .png, too.

Thanks to everyone for their help, and I hope this helps future modders fufill their dreams. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try registering the item like this:

```
Minecraft.getMinecraft().getRenderItem().getItemModelMesher().register(item, 0, new ModelResourceLocation(item.getUnlocalizedName(), "inventory"));
```

I´m not sure, but this should work!

-LPMG

Comment: No, that seems to disconnect the model entirely from the item. I'm guessing that I'm using an outdated base model.